# dropdown datepicker range date

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code for my datepicker text box:

```
 <!-- Setup Datepicker -->
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
 $(function() {

 $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   showOn: 'button',
   buttonImage: 'jquery/calendar.gif',
   buttonImageOnly: true
   });
   });
    --></script>
```

I would like to setup the year slide drop-down from 1910 to 2014.

I read the API but I´m new in coding and don´t understand and don´t know how to apply.

How can I do it?

What I have to put in this code for that?

How can I change the language from English to Spanish?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, working:

Add the option **yearRange: '1910:2014'**

```
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1910:2014'});
});

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
$(function() {
$.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
            closeText: 'Cerrar',
            prevText: '&#x3c;Ant',
            nextText: 'Sig&#x3e;',
            currentText: 'Hoy',
            monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio',
            'Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun',
            'Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Mi&eacute;rcoles','Jueves','Viernes','S&aacute;bado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mi&eacute;','Juv','Vie','S&aacute;b'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','S&aacute;'],
            weekHeader: 'Sm',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);

//for year list
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: '1910:2014'});
});

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```